# Write Round in NHibernate criteria

Tags: nhibernate, criteria, projection

I need to write this in NHibernate `Criteria` as a *projection*:

*The subAlias is _not_ the root alias, so {alias} cannot replace the correct sql alias, and my problem is that other parts of the query makes the subAlias vary in the generated sql*

```
ROUND(alias.Property / parameterValueFromMethodParameter + ", 0) 
   * parameterValueFromMethodParameter2 AS SQLAlias
```

This is how far (off) I got:

```
.Add(Projections.SqlFunction(new VarArgsSQLFunction("(", "/", ")")
     , NHibernateUtil.Int32
     , Projections.SqlFunction("round"
          , NHibernateUtil.Decimal
          , Projections.Property("subAlias.Property"))), "SQLAlias"))
```

This produces the following SQL code:

```
ROUND( subAlias3(4).Property
            )AS y1_
```

Does anyone have experience with projections like this?
I found this [patch](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2952) i hibernate, but seems like it was not implemented.

Comment: I tried to improve your formatting but you should really go through the code snippets you've pasted. They does not seem to be working ...

Comment: oh, thanks for the formatting :) It was just example "psuedo" code, not working code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved it by writing my own SQL IProjection. With a litte help from [this example](http://www.famvdploeg.com/blog/2011/12/nhibernate-sqlaliascriterion/).

```
 public SqlString ToSqlString(ICriteria criteria, int loc, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery, IDictionary<string, IFilter> enabledFilters)
    {
        string replacedString = Regex.Replace(
            this.sql, 
            @"{([a-zA-Z_]((\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9_])*)}", 
            m =>
                {
                    ICriteria critter = criteria.GetCriteriaByAlias(m.Groups[1].Value);
                    if (critter != null)
                    {
                        return criteriaQuery.GetSQLAlias(critter);
                    }

                    return m.Groups[0].Value;
                });

        return new SqlString(replacedString);
    }
```

So now I can do (In a SqlGroupProjection):

```
ROUND({subAlias}.XCoord / " + aggregationSize + ", 0) * " + aggregationSize + " AS SQLAlias
```

There are some other attempts on extending (N)Hibernate to handle this alias in raw SQL problem:

[Expression.Sql should support aliases other than {alias}](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1432?jql=text%20~%20%22alias%22)
[Support for referencing non-root entities in Criteria SQL expressions](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2952)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your example properly, the most easy solution would be to use SQL projection:

```
// the parameterValueFromMethodParameter 
// and parameterValueFromMethodParameter2 
var computationParams = new object[] {2, 4}; // just an example numbers

// SQL To be generated
// see that here we work with COLUMN name, not property
var sqlSnippet = " ( ROUND({{alias}}.ColumnName / {0}, 0) * {1} ) AS computed ";

// put that all together
var projectSql = string.Format(sqlSnippet, computationParams);

// IProjection
var projection = Projections.SqlProjection(projectSql, new string[0], new IType[0]);

// add it to SELECT clause
criteria.SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
           .Add(projection)
           ...
         );
```

That should work...

Comment: My problem is that {alias} is not the root alias it's a alias for another table. So I cannot get NH to replace {alias} with the correct generated sql alias. I've updated the question.

Comment: Well basically, this simply goes beyond standard ORM. One way could be to depend on *almost always the same alias* for not root table (e.g. notRoot3_). Or create custom SQL Subquery with filter to {alias}.ID... But anyhow. This can hardly be marked as a standard requirement for ORM query... sorry..

Comment: This is far from standard! I agree, but we have a big search query built on criteria, and it adds aliases depending on user selection, to be able to search on different fields. So even if it's not standard, we need to solve it :)

Comment: How much is changing the divide by and multiplied by? could these be treated as Constants? if yes... you can create new mapping. You can have a new property, with this computation on that non-root entity. That would be readonly defined with `formula=""` then you can query it very easily. But again. You can use Your OWN SELECT... subselect in fact, to be injected into SELECT clause. you can consume {alias}.ID of a root to be sure that proper row is selected. No other way as far as I know...

Comment: I tried to solve this without adding any code to nhibernate. But at last I got pragmatic and wrote another ToSqlString for IProjection. That works very well. Thanks for you help Radim!